# DIfferent behaviours of rsync

Tags: rsync, ownership

According to what I have understood, `rsync` without the `-o` and `-g` options is meant to copy without changing the owner and group of the destination. However, I found out a very strange behaviour of `rsync` that I cannot explain. An example being always better than a long explanation:

Let `file1` and `file2` be 2 files whose the group and owner are user1:user1 and user2:user2, respectively.

Running the following instructions (in 2 lines) with `user1` that is a sudoer:

```
touch file1
```

then

```
touch file2 && sudo chown user2:user2 file2 && rsync file1 file2 && ls -l
```

results in:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Jan 16 19:51 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Jan 16 19:53 file2
```

whereas running the following instructions, still with `user1`, all at once (1 line):

```
touch file1 && touch file2 && sudo chown user2:user2 file2 && rsync file1 file2 && ls -l
```

results in:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Jan 16 19:51 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user2 user2 0 Jan 16 19:53 file2
```

To summarise, in the first case the ownership of `file2` has been modified, whereas in the second one it has not been, it is still user2:user2, which is the expected behaviour (except if I have misunderstood) of `rsync`.

Maybe I missed something, but I cannot find what. Do you have any explanation please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are misinterpreting the function of `rsync`. Here's what the `-o` and `-g` options do according to the `rsync` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> `-o, --owner`
>   This option causes rsync to set the owner of the destination file to be the same as the source file, but only if the receiving rsync is being run as the super-user (see also the --super and --fake-super options). **Without this option, the owner of new and/or transferred files are set to the invoking user on the receiving side.**
>
> `-g, --group`
>   This option causes rsync to set the group of the destination file to be the same as the source file. If the receiving program is not running as the super-user (or if --no-super was specified), only groups that the invoking user on the receiving side is a member of will be preserved. **Without this option, the group is set to the default group of the invoking user on the receiving side.**

Because you're running `rsync` locally, *you* are the invoking user on the receiving side. If I'm understanding the man page correctly, there is no option to preserve the owner and group of the destination file, only that of the source file (through use of the `-o` and `-g` options) - so the behavior you're seeing is normal.

Answer (score 1):

By default, rsync compares timestamps with 1-second precision (although it transfers them in highest possible precision). As a result:

- In the 1st case, rsync considers file2 "out of date" (due to having a different timestamp than the source), so it deletes and re-creates it.

  You probably noticed that `chown` only works with `sudo`, because regular users cannot change file ownership – only root is allowed to do that. (Being a sudoer is not the same as being root.)

  The same applies to rsync; if it is running as a normal non-root user on the receiving side, it will be unable to restore the original file ownership and all files it creates will always be owned by the same user.
- In the 2nd case, both files have timestamps within the same second (usually), so rsync considers file2 "up-to-date" and does not modify it at all.

  See the `--modify-window` option – you can set it to `-1` if you want timestamps to be compared exactly, then the file will be re-created in both cases.